# To have two horizontal pages in LaTeX

Tags: layout, latex

I need to have codes in the format A4.
The codes are so long that I would like to make two pages in my document horizontal. Other pages should be vertical.

**How can you make two pages horizontal in LaTeX?**

Comment: LaTeX is a programming language. LaTeX questions are on topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install and include this package

```
\usepackage{lscape}
```

Then when you wan't to make a horizontal (landscape) page just use `landscape` environment

```
\begin{landscape}
horizontal content here
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: I am deleting my same solution below.  One small caveat.  If you are using pdflatex, make sure you use the pdflscape package.

More info: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lscape

Comment: @SplittingField: Thank you for pointing that out! - I had already an issue with `lscpape`.

Comment: pdflscape may be better if you are creating pdfs, but latex doesn't always produce pdfs so saying which one is better depends of what you are trying to do. Anyway, both packages gives you the same `landscape` that works rather well.

Comment: Agreed.  In general, I have found latex to be used as a more general term which includes latex, pdflatex, xelatex, etc.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, it should be noted that the lscape
package only works with Latex.  If you use pdfLatex,
you should use the pdflscape style.

For more information see this
[CTAN Link.](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lscape)

Comment: Do you know how you can have the pagenumbers also horizontally?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that?  it is generally against the "Standard Rules" for theses, etc.  And the answer is no, not off the top of my head.. ;-)